# Why is $A^{1/2} = Q$ where $Q$ has the property $A = QQ^H$ instead of the Q that has the property $A= QQ$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-exponential

Suppose $A$ is hermitian matrix such that $A = A^H$.

Exponentiating matrix $A$ is defined as $e^A = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{n!}A^n$

Where $A^n = \underbrace{A \cdots A}_{n-\text{times}}$.

Since $A^2 = AA$ we might reasonably expect $A^{1/2} = Q$ where $QQ = A$ but instead it's defined as the Q that solves $A = QQ^H$.

I was thinking that perhaps $A^H = A \iff Q = Q^H$ so that it doesn't matter but I don't think this is true.

Can I get some intuition (or even a numerical example) for why $A^{1/2} = Q$ where $QQ^H = A$?

Comment: Where did you see the definition of $A^{1/2}$ is the matrix $Q$ such that $QQ^H = A$?

Comment: For the same reason that it is easier to define $\sqrt{|x|}$ than $\sqrt x$ for complex numbers ;)

Comment: @Ovi it's in a electrical engineering textbook where they describe it as being analogous to the square root. Maybe that's loose engineering speak for that's how they like to think about it but there's no mathy way to show that's the case

Comment: @financial_physician Hmm then my best guess is that this definition is motivated by something in electrical engineering.

Answer (score 0):

For matrices over the real numbers, Hermitian matrices are precisely the symmetric matrices.  That is, $Q^H= Q$ so $QQ^H= QQ$.

Complex numbers do not have real square roots but $xx^T$, where $x^T$ is the complex conjugate of x, is a real number so we can take the square root if it.  Similarly, if Q is a matrix over the complex numbers we need $QQ^H$ to get real numbers.

Comment: I don't think it's the case that $Q^H = Q$ when you factor a matrix that's hermitian. If that's the case, it's not obvious to me